# How would i validate this form with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

This is my html

```
            <div><center><b class="cust_heading">ONLINE FREIGHT QUOTES</b><br>
Instant prices with multiple carriers</center>
            </div>

            <div class="field_heading"><b>Shipment type* </b><span id="shipmentError" class="cust_error"></span></div>
            <div class="fiftyPercent">
                <input type="radio" name="shipment" value="export"> Export
            </div>
            <div class="fiftyPercent">
                <input type="radio" name="shipment" value="import"> Import
            </div>

            <div class="field_heading"><b>Load type* </b><span id="loadError" class="cust_error"></span></div>
            <div class="fiftyPercent">
                <input type="radio" name="load" value="fcl"> FCL
            </div>
            <div class="fiftyPercent">
                <input type="radio" name="load" value="lcl"> LCL
            </div>


            <div style="display:none; width:100%;" id="weight_volume_row">
                <div class="fiftyPercent">
                Weight (kg)*<span id="lcl_weightError" class="cust_error"></span><br><input type="text" name="lcl_weight" id="lcl_weight" value="" placeholder="e.g 100" style=" width:70%;">
                </div>
                <div class="fiftyPercent"> 
                Volume (m<sup>3</sup>)*<span id="lcl_volumeError" class="cust_error"></span><br><input type="text" name="lcl_volume" id="lcl_volume" placeholder="e.g 1" value="" style=" width:70%;">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="field_heading"><b id="cust_include_text">Include pickup* </b><span id="pickupError" class="cust_error"></span></div>
            <div class="fiftyPercent">
                <input type="radio" name="pickup" value="yes"> Yes
            </div>
            <div class="fiftyPercent">
                <input type="radio" name="pickup" value="no"> No
            </div>



            <div class="field_heading"><b id="cust_zipcode_text">Pickup zip code* </b></div>

            <div style="width:100%;">
                <input id="pickupZipCode" placeholder="Enter a city or zip code" title="pickupZipCode" type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" style=" width:85%;"><input type="hidden" name="postal_hid_data" id="postal_hid_data" value="">
                <select name="choosePort" id="choosePort" style=" width:85%; display:none;"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Choose a port</option><option value="test1">test1</option><option value="test2">test2</option><option value="test3">test3</option></select>
                <select name="choosePortOther" id="choosePortOther" style=" width:85%; display:none;"><option value="">Choose a port</option><option value="test4">test4</option><option value="test5">test5</option><option value="test6">test6</option></select>
                <span id="zipError" class="cust_error"></span>
            </div>



        <div class="field_heading"><b id="cust_dest_text">Port of destination* </b></div>

            <div style="width:100%;padding:5px 0px;">
                <input id="destPort" placeholder="Enter a port or country" title="portDestination" type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" style=" width:85%;"><input type="hidden" name="des_hid_data" id="des_hid_data" value="">
        <span id="desError" class="cust_error"></span>
            </div>


        <div style="width:90%; float:left;padding:5px 0px;">
            <input class="searchButton orange-bttn cust_btn" id="cust_form_submit" name="cust_form_submit" type="submit" value="Buscar Naviera" style="float:right;">
        </div>  



                    </div>
```

and my jquery validate form is lookin like this, what is it im doing wrong. Using the wrong form id?

```
$(function() {
$('cust_main_box').validate({
    rules: {
        pickupZipCodeUS: {
            required: true
        },
        destPortUS: {
            required: true
        },
        //lcl_weightForm2US: {
            //required: true
        //},
        //lcl_volumeForm2US: {
            //required: true
        //},
    },
    messages: {
        pickupZipCodeUS: {
            required: 'Please enter a valid zip-code',
        },
        destPortUS: {
            required: 'Please enter a valid port',
        },
        //lcl_weightForm2US: {
            //required: 'Please enter a valid weight',
        //},
        //lcl_volumeForm2US: {
            //required: 'Please enter a valid volume',
        //},
    }
)};
```

});

The code that was commented out had to do with another form within the jquery, I'd like to include it whenever i figure out what it is i'm doing wrong.

Comment: The selector seems to be wrong, if it's supposed to be an ID selector, it should be `#cust_main_box`. And where is the form element? I can't find it.

Comment: that's what i assumed the issue was. My programmer used bootstrap, so i don't think there was a form...just a div and an "input type" class. Do you think that's what the problem is?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know the element that should be selected is a form element.

Comment: There should be a form with id `cust_main_box` and you should change the selector to `#cust_main_box`

Comment: Learn what label elements are.

Answer (score 2):

as @undefined already told you, proably the element should be `.cust_main_box` or `#cust_main_box`, but the problem in your code is validate closing:

```
)};
```

should be

```
});
```

So your correct JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#cust_main_box').validate({
        rules: {
            pickupZipCodeUS: {
                required: true
            },
            destPortUS: {
                required: true
            }
            //,lcl_weightForm2US: {
                //required: true
            //},
            //lcl_volumeForm2US: {
                //required: true
            //},
        },
        messages: {
            pickupZipCodeUS: {
                required: 'Please enter a valid zip-code'
            },
            destPortUS: {
                required: 'Please enter a valid port'
            }
            //,lcl_weightForm2US: {
                //required: 'Please enter a valid weight',
            //},
            //lcl_volumeForm2US: {
                //required: 'Please enter a valid volume',
            //},
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Even after adding `form` tags, your answer is incomplete/broken: http://jsfiddle.net/aawUK/

Answer (score 0):

Your major problems:

1)  The jQuery Validate plugin requires that all input elements to be validated **must** have `name` attributes.  Those `name` attributes must also be where your declared rules are assigned.

```
<input type="text" name="pickupZipCodeUS" ...
<input type="text" name="destPortUS" ...
```

2)  You are missing a `form` element.  The jQuery Validate plugin can only work when the user input elements are contained within a set of `<form></form>` tags.

3)  `$('cust_main_box')` is not a valid selector in this context.  Give the new `<form>` element an `id="cust_main_box"` and change the selector to `$('#cust_main_box')`.

```
<form id="cust_main_box" ...
```

4)  The closing braces for your `.validate()` call are reversed.  They should be this: `})`.

```
$('#cust_main_box').validate({
    // rules & options
}); // <-- this here
```

**Working Code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#cust_main_box').validate({
        rules: {
            pickupZipCodeUS: {  // <-- this is the field name
                required: true
            },
            destPortUS: {       // <-- this is the field name
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pickupZipCodeUS: {
                required: 'Please enter a valid zip-code',
            },
            destPortUS: {
                required: 'Please enter a valid port',
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/fTwsG/**

You're using a bunch of invalid and deprecated markup, so you should also put your HTML through the [W3C HTML Validation tool](http://validator.w3.org/).